# Find the image type from a memory stream

Tags: c#, jpeg, memorystream

I am writing some code to convert some images stored in a database to JPEG. I need to check if the image isn't JPEG, and all I have is a `byte[]` that I am putting into a `MemoryStream`. The current code then plugs that into a `Bitmap`, which doesn't tell me anything about the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [`Image.RawFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat.aspx) property. Once you load the image from the stream you could do:

```
if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(image.RawFormat))
{
    // Image is JPEG
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the first few bytes.  Most, but not all, JPEG files start with the byte sequence `FF D8 FF`.  If you need to be sure, you'll need to do a bit more.

I wrote a VB class fifteen years ago to do this.  I still find copies of it floating around the web:
https://code.google.com/p/vbgore/source/browse/trunk/Code/GrhDatMaker/CImageInfo.cls?spec=svn45&r=45

It's easy enough to read.  This should be faster than loading into an `Image` class.